# new table row is added under the first cell in the header

Tags: javascript, html-table

I was writing a function to create a table from some stored data, an issue occurred where all the cells in the `tbody` rows were added under the first cell in the `thead` and I noted that removing the thead solves the problem but I would not prefer to remove the `thead` as it facilitates other stuff in the project

Here is the data needed by the function

```
var courses = [
        [{name:'xxx',room:'Seminar 1'},{name:'xxx',room:'Seminar 1'},{name:'xxx',room:'Seminar 1'},
        {name:'zzz',room:'111'},{name:'zzz',room:'111'},{name:'zzz',room:'111'},{name:'Subject 3 - Instructor 3',room:'yyy'},{name:'Subject 4 - Instructor 4',room:'yyy'},{name:'Subject 5 - Instructor 5',room:'yyy'},{name:'Subject 5 - Instructor 5',room:'yyy'},{name:'Subject 6 - Instructor 6',room:'yyy'},{name:'Subject 6 - Instructor 6',room:'yyy'}],
        [{name:'',room:'',room:''},{name:'',room:''},{name:'xyz',room:'Semniar 1'},{name:'xyz',room:'Semniar 1'},{name:'',room:''},{name:'x',room:'1'},{name:'x',room:'1'},{name:'t',room:'2'},{name:'y',room:'2'},{name:'y',room:'3'},{name:'y',room:'3'},{name:'',room:''}],
        [{name:'',room:'',room:''},{name:'',room:''},{name:'',room:''},{name:'',room:''},{name:'',room:''},{name:'',room:''},{name:'',room:''},{name:'',room:''},{name:'',room:''},{name:'',room:''},{name:'',room:''},{name:'',room:''}],
        [{name:'',room:'',room:''},{name:'',room:''},{name:'',room:''},{name:'',room:''},{name:'',room:''},{name:'',room:''},{name:'',room:''},{name:'',room:''},{name:'',room:''},{name:'',room:''},{name:'',room:''},{name:'',room:''}],
        [{name:'',room:'',room:''},{name:'',room:''},{name:'',room:''},{name:'',room:''},{name:'',room:''},{name:'',room:''},{name:'',room:''},{name:'',room:''},{name:'',room:''},{name:'',room:''},{name:'',room:''},{name:'',room:''}],
        [{name:'',room:'',room:''},{name:'',room:''},{name:'',room:''},{name:'',room:''},{name:'',room:''},{name:'',room:''},{name:'',room:''},{name:'',room:''},{name:'',room:''},{name:'',room:''},{name:'',room:''},{name:'',room:''}]
          ];
          var days = ['Saturday','Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday'];
          var slots = {start:'08:00',duration:'1:00',count:15,breaks:[4,8,12],break_duration:'0:20'};
var arr = [[3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0],

[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1],


[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],


[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],


[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],


[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Here is the function to create the table

```
function tableCreate() {
var body = document.getElementById('tablediv');
var tbl = document.createElement('table');
tbl.setAttribute("id","myTable");

var thd = document.createElement('thead');
var row = document.createElement('tr');
thd.setAttribute("class","ant-table-thead");
var head = document.createElement('th')
head.setAttribute('rowspan',2);
head.setAttribute('colspan',1);
head.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Day'));
row.appendChild(head);
var start = slots.start,brk=0,end=undefined;
for(var i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        for(var j=0;j<slots.count;j++)
            {
            head = document.createElement('th')
            head.setAttribute('class','column1');
            head.setAttribute('colspan',1);
            if(i===0)
                head.appendChild(document.createTextNode(j+1));
            else{
                if(slots.breaks.length>brk && j+1===slots.breaks[brk])
                    {
                    end = calcTo(start,slots.break_duration);
                    brk++;
                    }
                else
                    end = calcTo(start,slots.duration);
                head.appendChild(document.createTextNode(start+'-'+end));
                start = end;
                }
            row.appendChild(head);
            }
    thd.appendChild(row);
    row = document.createElement('tr');
}
tbl.appendChild(thd);
var tbd = document.createElement('tbdoy');
for(var i=0;i<days.length;i++)
{   brk=0;
    for(var j=0;j<slots.count+1;j++)
    {   var td = document.createElement('td');
        if(j==0)
        {
            td.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(156, 52, 104)';
            td.style.color = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';
            td.style.textAlign = 'left';
            td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(days[i]));
            row.appendChild(td);
        }
        else{
            td.setAttribute("class","column1");
            if(slots.breaks.length>brk && j===slots.breaks[brk])
                {
                    if(i===0)
                    {
                        td.setAttribute('rowspan',days.length);
                        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('b'));
                        td.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
                        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('r'));
                        td.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
                        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('e'));
                        td.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
                        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('a'));
                        td.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
                        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('k'));
                        td.style.textAlign = 'center';
                        td.setAttribute("colspan",arr[i][j-1]);
                        row.appendChild(td);
                    }
                brk++;
                }
            else{
                var namespan = document.createElement('span');
                var roomspan = document.createElement('span');
                roomspan.style.color='red';
                roomspan.style.verticalAlign='bottom';
                roomspan.style.textAlign = 'right';
                roomspan.appendChild(document.createTextNode(courses[i][j-1-brk].room));
                namespan.style.textAlign = "center";
                namespan.appendChild(document.createTextNode(courses[i][j-1-brk].name));
                td.appendChild(namespan);
                td.appendChild(roomspan);
                td.setAttribute("colspan",arr[i][j-1]);
                if(arr[i][j-1]>0)
                row.appendChild(td);
                }

        }
    }
    tbd.appendChild(row);
    row = document.createElement('tr');
}



tbl.appendChild(tbd);
body.appendChild(tbl);
```

}

helper function calcTo:

```
function calcTo(from,dur)
{
    var minfrom = parseInt(from.slice(from.indexOf(':')+1));
    var mindur = parseInt(dur.slice(dur.indexOf(':')+1));
    var hourfrom = parseInt(from.slice(0,from.indexOf(':')));
    var hourdur = parseInt(dur.slice(0,dur.indexOf(':')));
    var summin=minfrom+mindur,sumhour=hourfrom+hourdur;
    if(summin > 59)
    {
      summin = 60-summin;
      sumhour = sumhour+1;
    }
    if(sumhour > 23)
    {
      sumhour = 24 - sumhour;
    }
    return (sumhour<10?'0'+sumhour:sumhour)+":"+(summin<10?'0'+summin:summin);
}
```

sorry for any inconvenience, if there are any suggestions for the question please let me know as it is my first time posting and thanks in advance.

**Edit:** I also noted that if I saved the html file generated and opened the saved file, the table is viewed as it should which means the html generated is proper with proper cell alignment so I would think it is script related or something

**Edit2:** I provided example data and somewhat proper indentation, thanks for coping with me and trying to help

Comment: We don't have the data this function loops over available, so there is no way for us to accurately reproduce your issue. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: This code is almost impossible to just look at and understand — the indentation is a mess. You have if/thens without brackets, which may or may not be bugs, it calls functions which you didn't include and it depends on data, which we would have to guess at to make your code work. Some of that data, like courses, seems to be multi-dimensional arrays. If you don't provide something people can run, it's going to be more work than most people want to do to help you.

Comment: ok thanks for the response I will include the needed data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce issue here for others:

Raw HTML Table:
    https://jsfiddle.net/wnvdnpud/
    `_`

VS Javascript Created Table:
    https://jsfiddle.net/worw1hv0/
    `_`

Here is Your Typo causing issue:

```
var tbd = document.createElement('tbdoy');
```

change to:

```
var tbd = document.createElement('tbody');
```

Comment: sure here you go and thanks for trying to help .. I didn't down rate you, sorry

var slots = {start:'08:00',duration:'1:00',count:15,breaks:[4,8,12],break_duration:'0:20'};

Comment: okay, and what about the calcTo() method? do you have that? thanks

Comment: thanks for the heads up, they are now in the post, if there is any missing items please let me know

Comment: I edited my answer, please accept, thank you. browser seems smart enough to correct the typo when in raw html for some reason crazy.

Comment: yeah thank I believe that's it .. I am confused also because it viewed normal when opened as raw html and my editor didn't alert to me such typo .. thanks again